# Where is the "New Genesis Hash Generator" code in newest Bitcoin source code?

Tags: genesis-block

I am trying to generate my own genesis hash by modifying some hardcoded parameter in main.cpp.

It worked in previous version of Bitcoin, but now it seems that the "Genesis Generator" has been removed.

Where is the "New Genesis Hash Generator" code in newest Bitcoin source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved!

The new genesis generator locates at "chainparams.cpp"